# ERROR Failed to get exclusive lock on the configuration file. Another VMware process might be running using the configuration file

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I have been using a virtual machine for a long time and have never had problems starting but now I have a problem:

Whenever I try to start it shows this error:

```
"Failed to get exclusive lock on the configuration file.  Another VMware process might be running using the configuration file."
```

If I click OK, the next message is:

```
"Error while powering on: Cannot find a valid peer process to connect to."
```

I tried to remove the `vmx.lck` folders, but that did not help.

I use `windows` operating system on local computer.

[image: folders and files]

Someone can help me ?

Comment: what are all the files and folders? is it possible to have the exact same `.vmx` used by 2 VMs ? (I expect you tried leaving only the `.vmx` and `.vmdk` files)

Comment: @azbarcea I have these files and folders

Comment: Ok, remove everything except `.vmx` and `.vmdk` files and run the machine again. That should completely wipe out anything corrupted within the machine state. Make a backup to those files if you don't consider it safe.

Answer (score 4):

> Ok, remove everything except .vmx and .vmdk files and run the machine
>   again. That should completely wipe out anything corrupted within the
>   machine state. Make a backup to those files if you don't consider it
>   safe. – azbarcea

The above comment from azbarcea is what worked for me.  If you can't delete the files because it says they're in use, restart the machine, then delete the files.  Also remember to delete the any folders with lck files

Answer (score 2):

These are the consequences of Windows updating. I rolled back to the previous version and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting your system..I have faced the same issue solved by just restarting the system.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by Repair VMWare Installation as doing it, all running files in background are closed here is a link to help you out in this situation
https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/vmware_failed_to_get_exclusive_lock_on_the_configuration_file_error.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue, normally deleting the `.lck` folders is enough.

If it's not you can check `TaskManager`. You man have a bunch of VMWare background tasks running.

If so ended all of them and tried to open the VM again.